# Grouping data together based on specific increment

Tags: python, binning

I have a 2D list in python like:

```
[['Xzavier Kaska', 1.04], ['Brent Barnaby', 1.13], ['Alena Holoien', 1.37], 
 ['Sam Surey', 1.37], ['Kash Nocella', 1.55], ['Ezequiel Gerraughty', 1.57], 
 ['Myah Linsley', 1.74], ['Jaelynn Dzur', 1.79], ['Alfredo Andrew', 1.83], 
 ['Skylar Movius', 1.95], ['Raphael Nocella', 2.14], ['Alondra Wallace', 2.2],
 ['Clark Loomis', 2.3], ['Skylar Cvek', 2.36], ['Carson Racugno', 2.52], 
 ['Kathy Viveros-aguilera', 2.62], ['Heaven Barnaby', 2.75], 
 ['Rebekah\tSpartichino', 3.24], ['Semaj Abernathy', 3.35], ['Rylee Dalton', 3.38], 
 ['Sterling Grove', 3.46], ['Rebekah Ghosh', 3.85]]
```

where index 0 represents student name and index 1 represents gpa of each student.

I want to group two pairs together in the above data based on increments of gpa's. Example: group them by increments of 1.0... students who have gpa `0.0-1.0` are unioned together, e.g. `[0.0-0.1), [0.1-0.2), ...[3.9-4.0]`;
`[0.0-0.5],[0.5-1.0),...[3.5-4]` ; `[0-1),[1,2),[2,3),[3,4)`.

Comment: Recommend using `pandas`, then you can simply do `df['GPA'].floordiv(0.5)` (or whatever bin-size) and `groupby` that. Then you can do whatever aggregation operation you want on each group, e.g. `mean()`, `count()`, etc.

Comment: What does *"group two pairs together"* mean? You only want to group records together in twos? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: This operation is called ***[tag:binning]***. Here, you're using bin-sizes of 0.1, 0.5, 1.0...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary and set key as a range, like if you want range 0-1 key of dict will be 1, range 4-5 key of dict will be 5 etc. So we can create a function that will group students with certain pace:

```
import math

l = [['Xzavier Kaska', 1.04], ['Brent Barnaby', 1.13], ['Alena Holoien', 1.37],
['Sam Surey', 1.37], ['Kash Nocella', 1.55], ['Ezequiel Gerraughty', 1.57], 
['Myah Linsley', 1.74], ['Jaelynn Dzur', 1.79], ['Alfredo Andrew', 1.83], 
['Skylar Movius', 1.95], ['Raphael Nocella', 2.14], ['Alondra Wallace', 2.2],
['Clark Loomis', 2.3], ['Skylar Cvek', 2.36], ['Carson Racugno', 2.52], 
['Kathy Viveros-aguilera', 2.62], ['Heaven Barnaby', 2.75], 
['Rebekah\tSpartichino', 3.24], ['Semaj Abernathy', 3.35], ['Rylee Dalton', 3.38], 
['Sterling Grove', 3.46], ['Rebekah Ghosh', 3.85]]

def group(l : list):
   """
   Group list students by their gpa with pace 1
   :param l: input list of students and gpa's
   :return: dictionary, where key is range: (key-1, key)
   ex. if you want to get list of students with gpa 1 :  d[1]
   """

   d = {}
   i = 0
   for student, gpa in l:
       index = math.ceil(gpa) - 1
       if index < 1: index = 1
       if index not in d.keys():
           d[index] = [[student, gpa]]
       else:
           d[index].append([student, gpa])
       i += 1

   return d

d = group(l)

# checking:

for i in group(l):
   print(f'range : {i-1} to {i}, list : {d[i]}')

# output will be:
# range : 0 to 1, list : [['Xzavier Kaska', 1.04], ['Brent Barnaby', 1.13], ['Alena Holoien', 1.37], ['Sam Surey', 1.37], ['Kash Nocella', 1.55], ['Ezequiel Gerraughty', 1.57], ['Myah Linsley', 1.74], ['Jaelynn Dzur', 1.79], ['Alfredo Andrew', 1.83], ['Skylar Movius', 1.95]]
# range : 1 to 2, list : [['Raphael Nocella', 2.14], ['Alondra Wallace', 2.2], ['Clark Loomis', 2.3], ['Skylar Cvek', 2.36], ['Carson Racugno', 2.52], ['Kathy Viveros-aguilera', 2.62], ['Heaven Barnaby', 2.75]]
# range : 2 to 3, list : [['Rebekah\tSpartichino', 3.24], ['Semaj Abernathy', 3.35], ['Rylee Dalton', 3.38], ['Sterling Grove', 3.46], ['Rebekah Ghosh', 3.85]]
```

Using dicts you can check numbers of students in certain group if group is not empty:

```
if 4 in d.keys():
    print(len(d[4]))
else:
    print('No students in such a group')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) which is a library used by data scientists in python. There's a ton of support online so you'll never get stuck.

For your particular issue:

```py
import pandas as pd

l = [['Xzavier Kaska', 1.04], ['Brent Barnaby', 1.13], ['Alena Holoien', 1.37], 
 ['Sam Surey', 1.37], ['Kash Nocella', 1.55], ['Ezequiel Gerraughty', 1.57], 
 ['Myah Linsley', 1.74], ['Jaelynn Dzur', 1.79], ['Alfredo Andrew', 1.83], 
 ['Skylar Movius', 1.95], ['Raphael Nocella', 2.14], ['Alondra Wallace', 2.2],
 ['Clark Loomis', 2.3], ['Skylar Cvek', 2.36], ['Carson Racugno', 2.52], 
 ['Kathy Viveros-aguilera', 2.62], ['Heaven Barnaby', 2.75], 
 ['Rebekah\tSpartichino', 3.24], ['Semaj Abernathy', 3.35], ['Rylee Dalton', 3.38], 
 ['Sterling Grove', 3.46], ['Rebekah Ghosh', 3.85]]

# Create a dataframe with your data.
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['Name','GPA'])
# select the portion of dataframe in which the GPA is between 1 and 2
# (you can set your own parameters here)
df2 = df.loc[(df['GPA'] > 1) & (df['GPA'] < 2)]
```

OUTPUT:

```
Name    GPA
0   Xzavier Kaska   1.04
1   Brent Barnaby   1.13
2   Alena Holoien   1.37
3   Sam Surey   1.37
4   Kash Nocella    1.55
5   Ezequiel Gerraughty     1.57
6   Myah Linsley    1.74
7   Jaelynn Dzur    1.79
8   Alfredo Andrew  1.83
9   Skylar Movius   1.95
```

If you then want to return a list like the one you have:

```py
list_1to2 = list(df2['Name'])
list_1to2.append('1-2')
print(list_1to2)
#repeat for each group...
```

OUTPUT:

```
['Xzavier Kaska', 'Brent Barnaby', 'Alena Holoien', 'Sam Surey', 'Kash Nocella', 'Ezequiel Gerraughty', 'Myah Linsley', 'Jaelynn Dzur', 'Alfredo Andrew', 'Skylar Movius', '1-2']
```

Comment: pandas has `df['GPA'].floordiv(0.5)`, best to use it, then groupby that

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Pandas for grouping and manipulate data:

```
import pandas as pd
step = 0.5
df = pd.DataFrame(gpas, columns=['name', 'gpa'])
df['group'] = df['gpa'].apply(lambda x:int(float(x) // step))
```

After that, you can create your group labels:

```
df['group_label'] = df['group'].apply(lambda x:'{}-{}'.format(x*step, (x+1)*step))
```

Result is like:

```
df.head()

name    gpa group   group_label
0   Xzavier Kaska   1.04    2   1.0-1.5
1   Brent Barnaby   1.13    2   1.0-1.5
2   Alena Holoien   1.37    2   1.0-1.5
3   Sam Surey   1.37    2   1.0-1.5
4   Kash Nocella    1.55    3   1.5-2.0
```

Comment: You don't need to define a `lambda x:int(float(x) // step)`, pandas directly offers `df['gpa'].floordiv(binsize)`